# Как сделать плавное съезжание блоков при добавлении нового?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Список блоков, ajax добавляет n блоков в начало, нужно что бы нижележащие блоки не просто прыгали вниз, а анимированно съезжали.
Прошу, помогите, битый час мучаюсь, ни одна мысль не сработала.
Можно Jquery, любые библиотеки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```js
function add(n) {
  $('div.el').css('background-color', 'wheat').css('top', function() {
    return (+$(this).css('top').split('px').shift()) + (n)*30 + "px";
  })
  
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
    $('button').after(`<div class="el" style="opacity:0; top:${30+i*30}px">hello</div>`)
 
  setTimeout(()=>$('div.el').css('opacity', 1))
}
```

```css
div.el {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 100ms;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='add(1+Math.round(Math.random()))'>add</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: Только есть одна проблема, добавляться может сразу несколько элементов, а у вас добавление идет по статическим 30px. У меня получается такое, что каждый следующий ответ сервера налазит на предыдущий

Comment: @mrCat сейчас что нибудь придумаю =)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n6xtvx
То как он работает, для лучшего понимания

Comment: @mrCat очень натянуто получилось, нужно знать число блоков и добавлять их изначально с правильным оффсетом, теперь в примере случайным образом добавляется 1 или 2 блока

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает!

Answer (score 2):

Прячешь блок - добавляешь его в документ - вызываешь `slideDown()`.
Если добавлять несколько элементов, тоже все нормально будет. Единственный нюанс: на мобилках, css-украшательства блоков (например, `box-shadow`) с такой анимацией, могут сильно напрягать железо.

---

Пример (кликай по превью):

```js
let ajaxResultHtml = '<div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>'; 

$(document).click(function () {
  $(ajaxResultHtml).hide(0).prependTo(document.body).slideDown(300); 
});
```

```css
.block {
  margin: 0.75rem 0.3rem; padding: 2rem 1rem; 
  font: 18px sans-serif; 
  border: 1px solid #aaa; background: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В местной песочнице почему-то сам меняется шрифт блоков, если их штук 8 добавить (просматриваю с мобилки) - хз почему так, [на jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qetaxigaca/edit?css,js,output) все ок.

Comment: Этот способ не подходит, он сдвигает блоки путем изменения высоты у добавляющихся, у меня новые блоки не должны менять своих размеров. Плюс к этому, у меня пк от таким образом 2х анимированных блоков подлагивает, боюсь представить что там будет другом железе.

Comment: @mrCat, то что "не подходит", это уже индивидуальные хотелки... с ними, пожалуйста, на фриланс-порталы. А вопрос был в том, "как можно реализовать анимацию при добавлении элементов в начало контейнера" - на этот вопрос и дан ответ. Насчет тормозов, конечно это не оптимальный вариант (jQuery ведь). Хотя моя мобилка 2012 г.в. вроде справляется, так что это может еще от браузера зависит. Рекомендую попробовать решение на чистом CSS (если у меня будет время, добавлю этот вариант).

Comment: + тут тоже все работает (хром винда)

Comment: Так я и не говорил, что не работает. Блоки имеют кучу стилей, иконки, разные шрифты, тени. На 2-х элементах начинает подлагивать, а уж что говорить о 5+, а их столько и будет. Так же само содержимое блоков искажается. Это хороший способ в некоторых ситуациях, но конкретно мне он не подходит.